# include data from different dataframes, combining different geoms and with a legend which identifies the data source

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three dataframes, containing data for the same variables (`x` and `y`, grouped by variable `case`) but each dataframe contains data from a different source (`test`, `sim` and `model`). The levels of `case` are identical for `test` and `model`, but they are different for `sim`. For each value of `case`,  I want all xy curves from different sources but with the same `case` to have the same color. I need to have a legend which clearly identifies the data source, but I would also like to use different geoms for different data sources. This is what I've been able to do:

```
rm(list=ls())
gc()
graphics.off()
library(ggplot2)

# build the dataframes
nx <- 10
x1 <- seq(0, 1, len = nx)
x2 <- x1+ 0.1
x3 <- x2+ 0.1
x4 <- x3+ 0.1
x <- c(x1, x2, x3, x4)
y1 <- 1 - x1
y2 <- 1.1 * y1
y3 <- 1.1 * y2
y4 <- 1.1 * y3
y <- c(y1, y2, y3, y4)
z1 <- (y1 + y2)/2
z2 <- (y2 + y3)/2
z3 <- (y3 + y4)/2
z4 <- (y4 + 1.1 * y4)/2
z <- c(z1, z2, z3, z4)
w <- y*1.01 

case_y <- c("I-26_1", "I00", "I20_5", "I40_9")
case_z <- c("I-23_6", "I00", "I22_4", "I42_3")
case_y <- rep(case_y, each = nx)
case_z <- rep(case_z, each = nx)

foo <- data.frame(x = x, y = z, case = case_z, type = "test")
bar <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, case = case_y, type = "sim")
mod <- data.frame(x = x, y = w, case = case_z, type = "model")

# different data frames have different factor levels: to avoid this,
# I bind all dataframes and I reorder the levels of case
foobar <- rbind(foo, bar, mod)
case_levels <- c("I-26_1", "I-23_6", "I00", "I20_5", "I22_4", "I40_9", "I42_3")
foobar$case <- factor(foobar$case, levels = case_levels)

# now I can plot the resulting dataframe
p <- ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) + 
geom_line(aes(linetype = type), size = 1)
p
```

[image]

The problem here is that it's difficult to discern `sim` and `model`. In order to make a more readable plot, I switch to `geom_point` for the `model` data:

```
foobar <- rbind(foo, bar)
case_levels <- c("I-26_1", "I-23_6", "I00", "I20_5", "I22_4", "I40_9", "I42_3")
foobar$case <- factor(foobar$case, levels = case_levels)
mod$case <- factor(mod$case, levels = case_levels)

# now I can plot the resulting dataframe
p <- ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype = type), size = 1) +
    geom_point(data = mod)
```

[image]

However, now I don't have a `model` label in the legend. How can I make sure that the `model` curves are clearly labeled in the legend, but they are also easy to discern visually from the `sim` and `test` curves?

**EDIT** Procrastinatus Maximus suggests an edit to Pierre Lafortune's code which should eliminate the space between the `model` label and the `type` legend, but apparently it eliminates the space between `model` and the `case` legend instead:

```
ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mod, aes(shape=type)) + 
  scale_shape_discrete(name="") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(1),
                                                   shape=c(NA)))) +
theme(legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0), legend.spacing = unit(0, 'lines'))
```

The result is

[image]

Comment: The desired output isn't clear but here's a start `geom_point(data = mod, aes(shape=type))`. More customization might require advanced editing of the `theme` function.

Comment: What is not clear? I want labels `test`, `sym` and `model` for each data set, but I also want to use different `geom`s or any other trick which allows me to clearly discern the three data sets in the plot. Your answer does the job: I was hoping it could be possible to have a single legend for `type` instead than two, but it's not strictly necessary. If you post it as an answer, I could accept it.

Comment: It was not clear whether you needed a separate legend or one. Or if the dots that are present in the 'case' legend must be removed.

Comment: @PierreLafortune ok, now it's clear what was not clear :) I'd like to have a single legend for `type`. I would also like to remove the dots from the `case` legend. However, I understand that extensive legend customization is difficult to achieve with `ggplot2`, so let's consider this point as a "nice to have", but not strictly necessary.

Comment: I added a piece of code to remove the dots.

Comment: We're almost there.

Comment: I think you should be okay now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you closer to your goal. I will look to see if we can close the gap between the two legends.

```
ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mod, aes(shape=type)) + 
  scale_shape_discrete(name="") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(1),
                                                   shape=c(NA))))
```

**Edit**

```
#@ProcrastinatusMaximus
ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = type), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mod, aes(shape = type)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1), shape = c(NA)), order = 1),
         linetype = guide_legend(order = 2),
         shape = guide_legend(title = NULL, order = 3))+
  theme(legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0), legend.spacing = unit(0, 'lines'))
```

[image]

Comment: You can eliminate the space between the legends completely by adding `theme(legend.margin = margin(0,0,0,0), legend.spacing = unit(0, 'lines'))` (which assumes you have the latest version of ggplot2)

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus, it doesn't seem to work: you eliminated the space between the `case` legend and the `model` entry, but the goal was to eliminate the space between the `type` legend and the `model` entry. See edited question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think all you need to do is change to order of the type, so that the solid line is in the middle. If you make the background white and the line colors a bit brighter, I think your figure is clear:

```
(p <- ggplot(data = foobar, aes(x = x, y = y, color = case)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = rev(type)), size = 1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black","green","blue","purple","pink","red","brown"))+
  theme_bw())
```

[image]